# WCF REST Service: Method parameter (object) is null

Tags: wcf, rest, webclient

why is the parameter of my WCF Rest service method always null?....I do access the service's method and i do get the string returned by the wcf method, but the parameter remains null.

Operation Contract:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddNewLocation",
        Method="POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string AddNewLocation(NearByAttractions newLocation);
```

Implementation of AddNewLocation method

```
 public string AddNewLocation(NearByAttractions newLocation)
    {
        if (newLocation == null)
        {
            //I'm always getting this text in my logfile
            Log.Write("In add new location:- Is Null");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Write("In add new location:- " );
        }

        //String is returned even though parameter is null
        return "59";
    }
```

Client code:

```
        WebClient clientNewLocation = new WebClient();
        clientNewLocation.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

        //Serialising location object to JSON
        string serialLocation = js.Serialize(newLocation);

        //uploading JSOn string and retrieve location's ID
        string jsonLocationID = clientNewLocation.UploadString(GetURL() + "AddNewLocation", serialLocation);
```

I also tried this code in my client but still get a null parameter

```
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NearByAttractions));

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, newLocation);

        String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());


        WebClient clientNewLocation = new WebClient();
        clientNewLocation.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        string r = clientNewLocation.UploadString(GetURL() + "AddNewLocation", json);

        Console.Write(r);
```

Then i also changed the **BodyStyle** option to "**Bare**" but then I got the following error (with both client codes):

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Any help please? thanks

**Edit 1:**
My GetUrl() method loads the web service IP address from the web config file and returns an object of type Uri

```
private static Uri GetURL()
    {
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");

        string sURL = config.AppSettings.Settings["serviceURL"].Value;
        Uri url = null;

        try
        {
            url = new Uri(sURL);
        }
        catch (UriFormatException ufe)
        {
            Log.Write(ufe.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
        {
            Log.Write(ane.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        return url;
    }
```

service address stored in web config as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="serviceURL" value="http://192.168.2.123:55666/TTWebService.svc/"/>
  </appSettings>
```

This is how my NearByAttraction class defined

```
 [DataContractAttribute]
public class NearByAttractions
{


    [DataMemberAttribute(Name = "ID")]
    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }



    [DataMemberAttribute(Name = "Latitude")]
    private string _Latitude;
    public string Latitude
    {
        get { return _Latitude; }
        set { _Latitude = value; }
    }


     [DataMemberAttribute(Name = "Longitude")]
    private string _Longitude;
    public string Longitude
    {
        get { return _Longitude; }
        set { _Longitude = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be in the right track. You need the `Bare` body style, otherwise you'd need to wrap the serialized version of your input in another JSON object. The second code should work - but without more information about how the service is set up and what `GetURL()` returns we can only guess.

One way to find out what to send to a WCF REST service is to use a WCF client itself for that - using the `WebChannelFactory<T>` class, then use a tool such as Fiddler to see what it's sending. The example below is a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) which shows your scenario working.

```
public class StackOverflow_15786448
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddNewLocation",
            Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string AddNewLocation(NearByAttractions newLocation);
    }
    public class NearByAttractions
    {
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lng { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string AddNewLocation(NearByAttractions newLocation)
        {
            if (newLocation == null)
            {
                //I'm always getting this text in my logfile
                Console.WriteLine("In add new location:- Is Null");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In add new location:- ");
            }

            //String is returned even though parameter is null
            return "59";
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        Console.WriteLine("Using WCF-based client (WebChannelFactory)");
        var factory = new WebChannelFactory<ITest>(new Uri(baseAddress));
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        var newLocation = new NearByAttractions { Lat = 12, Lng = -34, Name = "56" };
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.AddNewLocation(newLocation));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now with WebClient");

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NearByAttractions));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, newLocation);

        String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

        WebClient clientNewLocation = new WebClient();
        clientNewLocation.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        string r = clientNewLocation.UploadString(baseAddress + "/AddNewLocation", json);

        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had used "bare" as body style but then i get the "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." error

Answer (score 4):

Solved and thank you

I changed BodyStyle to **"Bare"** So my serivce interface is as follows:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddNewLocation",
        Method="POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string AddNewLocation(NearByAttractions newLocation);
```

Then implemented my client as follows:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        DataContractJsonSerializer serialToUpload = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NearByAttractions));
        serialToUpload.WriteObject(ms, newLocation);


        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

        client.UploadData(GetURL() + "AddNewLocation", "POST", ms.ToArray());
```

I used WebClient.UploadData instead of UploadString.